# How fast is the GLSL "determinant()" function

Tags: opengl, glsl

I'm programming a raytracer in GLSL and there are multiple algorithms for calculating the ray-triangle-intersection.
Some of these are using determinants some not, but the point is that calculating a determinant is slow.
So my question is : Is the determinant() function optimized on GPUs and how fast is it in comparison with multiplications.

Comment: I think it depends on GPU video card. I hope it is optimized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the GLSL `determinant()` function operates on *at most* 4x4 matrices, it won't do Gaussian elimination or anything like that. It's a few multiplications and additions/subtractions just as if you were to write the "unrolled" formula down by hand. For the 3x3 case it's about 12 multiplications and 5 addition/subtraction (using Cramer's rule) from which multiplications can be parallelized.

You can look at the [determinant implementation in the GLM library](https://github.com/g-truc/glm/blob/master/glm/detail/func_matrix.inl), the GLSL one is probably implemented very similarly, but of course it can vary between vendors/drivers/GPUs.

Comment: Could you elaborate how you came to 18 multiplications? Rule of Sarrus uses [12 multiplications for 3x3 matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_Sarrus)? And the glm implementation you linked cuts that down to 9 multiplications